# Permitir acesso ao FileSystem API do Chrome com Selenium usando Python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome, download, sistema-de-arquivos

Preciso de uma ajudinha aqui! Preciso de configurar o `selenium` usando o webdrive para clicar em uma janela pop-up do Chrome. Já tentei várias alternativas que achei, mas nenhuma funciona. Uma política de segurança da empresa restringe algumas configurações, mas o download automático é possível ser feito, mas o download automático é executado somente depois de clicar em Permito (Permitir). O Chrome pergunta “Armazenar arquivos neste dispositivo”, com as opções Permitir ou Bloquear. Conforme imagem.

[image: Armazenar arquivos neste dispositivo]

Esse foi o código utilizado:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time


option = Options()
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_argument('--disable-download-notification')
option.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", {
                "safebrowsing.enabled": True, 
                "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 1, 
                "profile.default_content_setting_values.geolocation": 1})

wd = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=option, executable_path='C:\\Users\\Documents\\webdriver\\chromedriver.exe')
wd.get('http://websiteintranet.com.br')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isto é uma medida de segurança Chrome quando um website tenta utilizar o [Chrome FileSystem API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage#filesystem).

Caso tenhas plena confiança no website que estás a aceder, podes fazer bypass a esse pop-up ao iniciar o chrome com a flag `--unlimited-storage`

```
option.add_argument("--unlimited-storage")
```

Comment: funcionou, era exatamente isso!!! Obrigado